# Formatting number in Nepali

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use [Intl NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) to represent Nepal's number format. I am a Nepali and I know how we use number in Nepali. It's exactly similar to Hindi language.

```
1,23,343.32
```

From last, the comma used after 3 digits and then 2 digits on next occurrence.

The intl number format works with Indian:

```js
let number = 123456.789
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN').format(number));
```

But it doesn't work with Nepali:

```js
let number = 123456.789
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-NP').format(number));
```

After digging deeper, I found it's not ECMAScript issue. ECMAScript uses [IANA number](https://www.iana.org/) and I found no form to submit a bug or issue or complaint and also I found IANA uses [ICANN number](https://pti.icann.org/) and there too I couldn't find where I can submit a bug or issue...

I know I can use `en-IN` to format it in Nepali as well. But I think this is overrule for me. And I know SO is not for asking where to complaint about something, but it's related to JavaScript number format issue somehow and asking here. If anyone can point out where I can submit an issue would be helpful.